# Don't MIME types like images or PDF files need to be base64 or otherwise encoded?

Tags: http, base64, http-post, urlencode, mime

Don't MIME types like images or PDF files need to be base64 or otherwise encoded 
when wanting to send them or upload them over HTTP, since they could potentialy contain control characters?

Don't binary data need a separate tratment from the textual ones, or could I even transfer a text file as binary data (application/octet-stream) and let the receiving application decide how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP request doesn't need any transfer encoding. Properly constructed HTTP POST request with `multipart/form-data` would include `Content-Type` for each section through every boundary. Don't need to think about it as MIME message. Server/application, this HTTP request addressed to, will handle each boundary content according to content headers and in particular `Content-Type`. The small example of HTTP POST payload may look like ...

```
POST /my_page HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MNZ2WM28FYlZX3miY-6E9iytpT0UfW-uzlOvF

--MNZ2WM28FYlZX3miY-6E9iytpT0UfW-uzlOvF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"

content of this input field
--MNZ2WM28FYlZX3miY-6E9iytpT0UfW-uzlOvF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="html_content"

<p><em>Dear customer</em>,</p>
<p>Please review the attached.</p>
--MNZ2WM28FYlZX3miY-6E9iytpT0UfW-uzlOvF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file0"; filename="sample.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Plain text file content.
--MNZ2WM28FYlZX3miY-6E9iytpT0UfW-uzlOvF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="sample.docx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

PK     ! ß¤ÒlZ      [Content_Types].xml ¢(  
l"%3÷Þ3VÆƒÑÚšl  µw%ë=–“^i7+Ù×ä-d&á”0ÞAÉ6€l4¼½L60#µÃ’ÍS
Oœ£œƒXø Ž*•V$z3„ü3à÷½Þ—Þ%p)Oµ^ “²×5}nH"dÙsÓXg•L„
    Á  8    
--MNZ2WM28FYlZX3miY-6E9iytpT0UfW-uzlOvF--
```